# Boolean True/False/None

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Probably stupid or already answered question here, sorry about that.

I know by definition a Boolean is supposed to have 2 values but I was wondering **what is the good practice in Django to store a "third" `None` value let's say for optional Boolean fields**.

So far I use a `CharField` or a `ChoiceField` with "yes", "no", "no_data" but I feel like it's not optimal. Is there a better way maybe using a special BooleanField that could store true/false/null or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django has [**`NullBooleanField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.NullBooleanField) this is a subclass of a [**`BooleanField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.BooleanField) but where both `null=True` and `blank=True` hold.

In [django-2.1](/questions/tagged/django-2.1), the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield) mentions that `null=True` is allowed for a `BooleanField`, and that the `NullBooleanField` will probably get deprecated:

> In older versions, this field doesn’t permit `null=True`, so you have to
>   use `NullBooleanField` instead. Using the **latter is now discouraged** as
>   it’s likely to be deprecated in a future version of Django.

In the more early versions of Django, it was thus impossible to write `BooleanField(null=True)`, but that behavior has changed.

Regardless what will be used, the idea is that the database can store three possible values: `TRUE` (mapping to `True`), `FALSE` (mapping to `False`), and `NULL` (mapping to `None`).

Note that just like `CharField`s, you can set `choices` to let the values map on more "sensical" displays.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`NullBooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.NullBooleanField) for this.

Comment: I thought using `NullBooleanField` was just storing `False` as `null` instead of `0`, thanks for the quick answer.